# Asignar valores dependiendo de las listas iniciales

Tags: python, python-2.7

En el siguiente código tenemos:

emparejamientos: variable que pretende representar parejas de jugadores. En el ejemplo, jugador 1 juega con jugador 2 y jugador 3 juega con jugador 4.

V1, V2, V3, V4: son variantes o símbolos que los jugadores muestran a sus oponentes en la pareja.

Senal_observadaX: son diccionarios donde queremos almacenar las señales que cada participante observa de su oponente.

Como se puede comprobar, el código funciona, pero me gustaría almacenar las señales de una manera más elegante y eficiente. Es decir, me gustaría que al intercambiar los valores (jugadores) en las listas iniciales (por ejemplo, cambiar a `([[1,3],[2,4]])`, el programa almacenase correctamente las señales que cada jugador ha observado. Es decir, que las memorias de los jugadores guardasen siempre la señal que ha sigo asignada a su pareja en la lista inicial. Que si jugador 1 juega con 2 almacene en su diccionario V2, que si juega con 3 almacene V3 y que si juega con 4 almacene V4.

```
emparejamientos= ([[1,2],[3,4]])

V1="V1"
V2="V2"
V3="V3"
V4="V4"

Senal_observada1 = {"V1":0,"V2":0,"V3":0,"V4":0}
Senal_observada2 = {"V1":0,"V2":0,"V3":0,"V4":0} 
Senal_observada3 = {"V1":0,"V2":0,"V3":0,"V4":0}
Senal_observada4 = {"V1":0,"V2":0,"V3":0,"V4":0} 

#Almacén de senales observadas en la memoria
if emparejamientos[0]==[1,2]:
     Senal_observada1[V2] +=1
     Senal_observada2[V1] +=1

if emparejamientos[1]==[3,4]:
     Senal_observada3[V4] += 1
     Senal_observada4[V3] += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer te valdría con almacenar todas las señales en un solo diccionario, en el que la clave es el par **(jugador, señal)**.

Y guardar el símbolo mostrado por cada jugador en una lista donde la primera posición es jugador1, la segunda jugador2,  etc:

```
emparejamientos= [(1,2), (3,4)]

# Simbolos mostrados por cada jugador
simbolo = [V1, V2, V3, V4]

# Almacen de señales vistas
senales = {
    (1, V1):0, (1, V2):0, (1, V3):0, (1, V4):0,
    (2, V1):0, (2, V2):0, (2, V3):0, (2, V4):0,
    (3, V1):0, (3, V2):0, (3, V3):0, (3, V4):0,
    (4, V1):0, (4, V2):0, (4, V3):0, (4, V4):0 }

#Almacenar para jugador las señales mostradas por el otro
for jugador1, jugador2 in emparejamientos:
    senales[(jugador1, simbolo(jugador2))] += 1
    senales[(jugador2, simbolo(jugador1))] += 1
```

En realidad ni necesitas inicializar el diccionario:

```
from collections import defaultdict
....
senales = defaultdict(int)
....
```

Pero por lo que he visto en esta pregunta y otra anterior, lo que de deberías hacer para que tu código sea mas legible es separarlo en **funciones**.